# calculate the name of a sessionScope in data tab combobox

Tags: combobox, xpages

I have a combobox. The selectable items are calculated and have the following layout :

```
 label1 | type1$$code1
 lable2 | type2$$code2
 label3 | type3$$code3
 etc ..
```

Now I would like to bind the selected value to a sessionScope with the name type1 when the first item is selected , type2 when the second item is selected etc.

So when the first item is sected it would become something like

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox4" value="#{sessionScope.type1}"></xp:comboBox>
```

When the second item is selected it should become something like:

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox4" value="#{sessionScope.type2}"></xp:comboBox>
```

etc ...

Comment: Imagine user clicks all the options one by one. You end up with all the types in sessionScope, with no information which one is selected.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way to handle your requirements would be to work with a `valueChangeListener`:

### XPAGE:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:panel id="panel1">

        <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" valueChangeListener="#{comboBoxController.valueChanged}">
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="label1" itemValue="type1$$code1"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="label2" itemValue="type2$$code2"></xp:selectItem>
            <xp:selectItem itemLabel="label3" itemValue="type3$$code3"></xp:selectItem>
        </xp:comboBox>

        <br />
        <br />
        <xp:button value="Partial Refresh" id="button1">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="true"
                refreshId="panel1"></xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>

    </xp:panel>


</xp:view>
```

### faces-config.xml:

```xml
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>comboBoxController</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>org.test.ui.controller.ComboBoxController</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
```

### ComboBoxController:

```java
package org.test.ui.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;

import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil;


public class ComboBoxController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void valueChanged(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {

        System.out.println("oldValue: " + valueChangeEvent.getOldValue());
        System.out.println("newValue: " + valueChangeEvent.getNewValue());

        String varname = valueChangeEvent.getNewValue().toString().substring(0, 5);

        System.out.println("varname: " + varname);
        System.out.println("value: " + valueChangeEvent.getNewValue());

        ExtLibUtil.getSessionScope().put(varname, valueChangeEvent.getNewValue());

    }

}
```

I hope I can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Write the selected value into a sessionScope variable 'type' and use it's value as name for the sessionScope variable you want to set with `sessionScope[sessionScope.type]`.

You can set it as value property in a second comboBox

```xml
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox5" value="#{sessionScope[sessionScope.type]}">
            ...
</xp:comboBox>
```

So, if your comboBox4 has the value "type1" for example then comboBox5 would read and write values in sessionScope variable `sessionScope.type1`.

```xml
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox4" value="#{sessionScope.type}">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="comboBox5" 
        execMode="partial" execId="comboBox4">
    </xp:eventHandler>
    <xp:selectItems>
        ...
    </xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>

<xp:comboBox id="comboBox5" value="#{sessionScope[sessionScope.type]}">
            ...
</xp:comboBox>
```